# ggplot2: Add line above strip text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really like the lines above the strip text like the economist does on their faceted graphs (Above "Female share, %").

[image: The economist, faceted plot]

I've tried two ways and neither of them has worked for me.

## My tries so far

## 1) Replace the strip backround

I created a grob with a line in the top right corner, and replaced the strip backround with it:

```
gg_red <- ggplot() + theme(plot.background = element_rect("#832301"))

top_line <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(gg_red,
                        layout_matrix  = matrix(c(1, NA, NA, NA), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2),
                        heights = c(1, 50),
                        widths = c(1,1),
                        padding = 0
                        )
```

And then I replaced the background of the strip with it.

This kind of worked, but was really ugly

### 2) Format the facet variable before plotting:

I created a function that adds a bar on the first three letters.

```
underline_strips <- function(x, nchar = 3){
    first <- x %>% str_sub(end = nchar)
    last <- x %>% str_sub(start = nchar + 1)
    return(paste0("bar('", first, "')*plain('", last,"')")) }
```

This worked decently with a single line, but when I used it in conjunction with str_wrap, either before or after, it turned out horribly.

In general, I would love it if ggplot would be more flexible outside the panels, without the need for a deep understanding on the grid package. Anyways, I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
anno_rect <- data.frame(x1 = c(1.3, NA), x2 = c(2, NA), 
                        y1 = c(39, NA), y2 = c(40, NA), 
                        vs = c(0, 1))

anno_line <- data.frame(x1 = c(1.3, 1, 5.7, 5.7),
                        y1 = c(40, 40, 40, 40),
                        vs = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_line()  +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1.2, .5, 0, 0, "cm"),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.background.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, 5.5), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off") +
  geom_rect(
    data = anno_rect,
    aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2, fill = "red"),
    inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_line(
    data = anno_line,
    aes(x = x1, y = y1, color = "red"),
    inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  annotate("segment", x = 1.3, xend = 1.6, y = 38, yend = 38) +
  facet_wrap(~ vs)
```

We are creating data.frames for the annotations to bypass the formatting of the facet function.  Some adjustments of the margin and plotting area are necessary to make this work.

To make this "automatic", you will need to extract some parameters from your faceted plot via `ggplot_build()` and use them to populate your annotation data.frames and parameters, and your `coord_cartesian()` limits.

You could also look into `paste()` to add `___ \n` to your facet labels.